# Get all columns from other tables with a distinct

Tags: sql

I am doing a distinct to filter by 2 columns, but I need it to bring me all the columns of the query, in this case it only brings me "idMes" and "idAnio", I need it to show me the other columns as well.
How could I do it?

this is my sentence:

`SELECT DISTINCT e.idMes, e.idAnio FROM expensas as e INNER JOIN anios as a on e.idAnio = a.idAnio INNER JOIN meses as m on e.idMes = m.idMes;`

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  If you want one row, how are the values of the extra columns determined?

Comment: You can write something like this if your database supports it `select * from expensas a inner join (select distinct e.idMes, ...) b on a.idmes = b.idmes and a.idanios = b.idanio;`

Answer (score 1):

`Select *` gives you all columns